# Android - Issue With OnClickListener and OnLongClickListener

Tags: android, layout, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I first inflate a Layout and later add a View to it using addView(). The layout has an OnLongClickListener attachted to it.

If I now add an OnClickListener to the inner view, the OnLongClickListener does no longer fire. How can I fix this?

Sample Code:

```
View someLayout =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
someLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            ...
        return true;
        }
});

TextView innerView = new TextView(this);

innerView.setText("JustSomeTextThatDoesNotMatter");
innerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ...
    );
}
});

((FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.framelayout)).addView(innerView);
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any Ideas? This really seems rather odd.

**Update**: The same thing happens when I use an onTouchListener instead of an onLongClickListener, the OnClickListener in the inner view consumes all touch events.

Is this by design? What I want basically is the same functionality that the ContextMenu provides to a ListView.

Comment: A simplest solution would be to add same OnLongClickListener to innerView too. More complex solution would be to implement touch onInterceptTouchEvent() method in the parent LinearLayout and implement LongPressListener there.

Comment: Just make sure that you are following onLongClickListener return value rule. Means that if you want to pass long click to parent view then return false otherwise return true. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Comment: I assume the `OnLongClick()` listener no longer fires for the `TextView` only but is ok elsewhere on the layout?

Comment: First try to figure out what you need in your case, is it to past OnClick Event or just to notify some function (which is usualy fired when you click just on your layout) when you clicked on TextView. So you can bypass this or try looking at intercepting TouchEvent like @Beworker suggested. Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: @beworker I need the LongClickListener to be attatached to the outer Class. An OnTouch-Listener would work but I would want to avoid such a  a manual solution.

rAvinder: the OnClickListener consumes the OnLongClicklistener, not the other way around. OnClickLister is return type void

Kerry: Did not test that, but when I remove the OnClickListener it works again, so probably yes.

Comment: You should add a @ to each user's name if you are trying to tag them, not just the first one.

Comment: @csmckelvey that only works for one user per comment. I will split my replies into multiple comments next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A clickable `View` consumes all touch events and prevents them from being returned to the parent. Therefore the only way to register for long clicks on the whole area of a layout containing clickable `View`s is to also register the listener on every clickable `View` inside the layout.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So how does the ContextMenu pattern work? If you call registerForContextMenu on a ListView, all LongClicks are caught, regardless of any CLickListeners in the list items.

Comment: @PhilippEbert: Registering a `ContextMenu` (whether on a `ListView` or something else) doesn't do anything special beyond making the view long clickable, so it shouldn't have any different behavior.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if this was explained in the documentation.

Comment: @corsair992 I am trying to solve for a similar problem.  I'd appreciate any insights or thoughts, located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783631/recyclerview-how-to-add-onclick-and-keep-onlongclick-working